# Thymeleaf+Spring Boot: form emptying object attributes

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm creating a simple CRUD in Spring Boot+Thymeleaf and all other CRUD on application work well but this one. When I submit the form, the object comes with empty attributes to controller.

In the following, the code:

Artist.java

```
@Entity
public class Artist {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false, length = 80)
    private String artistName;

    <getters and setters>
```

ArtistController.java

```
@Controller
public class ArtistController {

    @Autowired
    ArtistRepository artistRepository;

    @GetMapping("/artist/add")
    public String addArtist(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("artist", new Artist());
        return "artist/form_artist";
    }

    @PostMapping("/artist/save")
    public String artistSave(@ModelAttribute(name="artist") Artist artist) {

        artistRepository.save(artist);
        return "redirect:/artist";
    }
}
```

And now, the form:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/artist/save}" th:object="${artist}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id" >HobbyOn id:</label>
        <input type="text" id="id" th:field="*{id}" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" placeholder="hobbyOn ID" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="artistName" >Artist Name:</label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{artistName}" class="form-control" required="required" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
    </div>
</form>
```

I can't see any difference from examples in internet and in my own code. Any help will be very welcomed.

Comment: Have just tried a similar example: works for me. It is hard to tell exactly what is wrong. Could you please upload a complete minimal example (zip archive) somewhere?

Comment: A [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in github would be nice.

Comment: the only thing it occurs to me is remove @ModelAttribute(name="artist") from your POST method.